# What are these types of OTB events from the USCF?

Tags: tournament, terminology, uscf, otb-chess

Looking into OTB tournaments, I see that the USCF allows you to filter searches for the following types:

- Heritage Event
- American Classic
- Grand Prix
- Enhanced Grand Prix
- Junior Grand Prix
- National Championship Event
- State Championship Event
- Regionals

Some of these are self-evident, but what are "Heritage," "Classic," "Grand Prix," and "Enhanced" types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the Saint Louis Chess Club](https://saintlouischessclub.org/events/weekly-tournaments/other-tournament-information):

- National Events.  Co-sponsored by the USCF, these events offer official U.S. titles and most are open to bidding by USCF affiliates.  *(Meaning that any affiliate - such as a club or organization holding USCF affiliation - may make a bid to host these tournaments.)*
- Grand Prix.  Major events, usually open to all, listed in date order.  See "USCF GRAND PRIX" for more information.
- American Classics.  Events that are open to all and have attracted more than 400 players for three consecutive years.
- Heritage Events.  Tournaments held for at least 25 years.

I could not find a "USCF GRAND PRIX" section on the Saint Louis Chess Club's website, but [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USCF_Grand_Prix) says:

> The USCF Grand Prix is a set of chess tournaments for prize money
> rated by the United States Chess Federation. In general, a tournament
> must have at least $300 in guaranteed prizes to award "Grand Prix"
> points.
>
> At the end of the year, prizes are awarded to players with the most
> points. The first prize is usually $10,000.
>
> These prizes provide incentives to grandmasters to play in small
> regional tournaments which they would otherwise avoid.

I could not find a specific definition of "Enhanced Grand Prix", but from context of things I did find, it appears that "Enhanced Grand Prix" refers to tournaments that offer a larger number of Grand Prix points due to having a larger guaranteed prize pool.  It also appears (according to this [news item](http://www.chessnews.org/lower.htm)) that holding an "Enhanced Grand Prix" event requires the organizer to make a mandatory contribution to the USCF Professional Players Health and Benefit Fund.

"Junior Grand Prix" is a separate Grand Prix competition for Junior players (under 21 years old).

{Added 10/23/2022} A complete description of US Chess Grand Prix is available at https://new.uschess.org/us-chess-grand-prix-program.